# Display Treeview data on click and hide on click - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have this little Tkinter treeview program where data is being displayed in form of table and there is also a button there. So what I want to know is to be able to hide and display the data of table just by clicking the same display button. like if i click once it shows and when i click it again it hides its data.

With data I mean all IDs and Names it showing

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

ID = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Names = ['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim']

window = tk.Tk()
window.state('zoomed')
treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse')
treev.place(width= 250, height= 500, x=300, y=100)


verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window,
                           orient ="vertical",
                           command = treev.yview)

verscrlbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='y')
treev.configure(yscrollcommand = verscrlbar.set)


treev["columns"] = ('1', '2')

treev['show'] = 'headings'

treev.column("1", width = 90, anchor ='c')
treev.column("2", width = 90, anchor ='c')


treev.heading("1", text ="ID")
treev.heading("2", text ="Names")

for x, y in zip(ID, Names):
    treev.insert("", 'end', values =(x, y))

displaybutton = Button(window, text="Display", width=15, height=2, background= 'brown')
displaybutton.place(x=600, y=400)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should it hide all the rows or the selected row?

Comment: All the rows i.e all names and ids

Comment: should it still display column names?

Comment: Yes should only hide rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We  create this by simply inserting the values in the treeview on click and for the next click we can delete everything we inserted in the treeview.

```
a = 2
def showhide():
    global a
    if a%2 == 0:
        for x, y in zip(ID, Names):
            treev.insert("", 'end', values =(x, y))

        a= a+1
    else:
        c = treev.get_children()
        for child in c:
            treev.delete(child)
        a= a+1
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of doing it is to detach the rows one by one. To achieve this you need to store all the item `iid` in an array. `treev.get_children()` will return all the item id. Which you may later use to remove and display rows using `detach()` and `reattach()`(or `move()`)

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def hide():
    
    global a
        
    if not treev.get_children():
       for  x, child in enumerate(a):
           treev.reattach(item=child, parent=treev.parent(a[0]), index=x) # or you could give parent as an empty string like parent=''

    else:
        for child in a:
            treev.detach(child)
 

window = tk.Tk()
window.state('zoomed')
treev = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode ='browse')
treev.place(width= 250, height= 500, x=300, y=100)


verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window,
                           orient ="vertical",
                           command = treev.yview)

verscrlbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='y')
treev.configure(yscrollcommand = verscrlbar.set)

clicked = False
treev["columns"] = ('1', '2')

treev['show'] = 'headings'

ID = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Names = ['Tom', 'Rob', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim', 'Kim']

treev.column("1", width = 90, anchor ='c')
treev.column("2", width = 90, anchor ='c')


treev.heading("1", text ="ID")
treev.heading("2", text ="Names")

for x, y in zip(ID, Names):
    treev.insert("", 'end', values =(x, y))

a = treev.get_children()

displaybutton = Button(window, text="Display", width=15, height=2, background= 'brown', command=hide)
displaybutton.place(x=600, y=400)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks I understand but is there any other way just asking?

Comment: @YashuCッ  `treev['display']=''` but this will make all the rows including column names disappear. To bring it back `treev[display]='#all'`

Comment: Hello i want to if can do this by you know deleting the inserted values and inserting values again?

Comment: @YashuCッ Yes, you can but that's not necessary since you only want to hide them.

Comment: Actually i am making a project where i have to show student data in similar way but i am getting error while trying to this and the project is quite big.

Comment: self.tk.call(self._w, "detach", items)
_tkinter.TclError: Item 1 not found and when i remove detach i get same error for reattach